# terraform conditional express or coalesce with different data types

Tags: terraform

trying to make a module for terraform secrets manager and was hoping to switch on the secret type. key/value, string, etc.

```
module "kv_secret" {
type = "kv"
name = x
secret_data ={
  key = value
  }
etc etc
}
```

Then on the resource creation, if secret type is a string it'll just be

> secret_string = var.secret_data

if secret type is "kv" then

> secret_string = jsonencode(var.secret_data)

But for a conditional or coalesce either side need to be the same.. So the following would fail.

> var.secret_type == "kv" ? jsonencode(var.secret_data) : var.secret_data

Is there a way to accomplish a similiar action to get the result i am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, Terraform's conditional operator is designed for choosing between two values of the same type, rather than choosing between two different types.

One way to resolve this would be to make it the caller's responsibility to deal with this distinction: instead of having the caller specify both a value *and* whether to JSON-encode it, you could remove `var.secret_type` and have the caller do their own `jsonencode` call if they need it; that doesn't significantly change the separation of concerns, because the caller was already needing to distinguish between these two cases anyway, and will just now be doing so in a slightly different way.

If handling this inside the module is important for a reason not visible in your question then a way to achieve it would be to reformulate it as a lookup with a dynamic index/key, which would always be of the same type. For example:

```
locals {
  secret_encodings = {
    kv  = jsonencode(var.secret_data)
    raw = var.secret.data
  }
}
```

```
local.secret_encodings[var.secret_type]
```

(Here I've guessed that the other valid value of `secret_type` would be `"raw"`, but of course you should adjust that if you want that mode to have a different name.)

Because `local.secret_encodings` has an object type here, Terraform infers the type of the result by taking the attribute type corresponding to the given `var.secret_type`, and thus the two results can have different types in this situation. However, this does mean that the result type of this expression won't *necessarily* be predictable during validation, unless `var.secret_type` is set to a constant value in the module call as it was in your example, and so Terraform may not catch certain errors until the plan or apply step.